# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch users from my firebase database. I want all users to appear on the table view. I am trying to create a dictionary in order to do that but keep getting this error:

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Here's my code:

```
func fetchUser() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] != nil {
                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
                print(user.name!, user.email!)
            }
            print("User found")
            print(snapshot)
            
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `!= nil`, then is *has Optional type*

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your code like this

```
func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else{ return }
            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            print(user.name!, user.email!)
        }
        print("User found")
        print(snapshot)
        
    }, withCancel: nil)
   }
 }
```